# convert freeform sql to active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, haml, model-associations

i have this sql query that i want to be able to use within my ruby on rails project

Query

```
select menu_items.name, menu_attributes.name, 
menu_attributes_menu_items_venues.menu_attribute_value from menu_attributes, menu_items, menu_attributes_menu_items_venues, venues
where menu_items.id = menu_attributes_menu_items_venues.menu_item_id
and menu_attributes.id = menu_attributes_menu_items_venues.menu_attribute_id
and venues.id = menu_attributes_menu_items_venues.venue_id
and menu_attributes.name = 'Price'
```

I have my models setup like

Venues

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :menu_items
has_and_belongs_to_many :menu_attributes_menu_items_venues
```

Menu Attributes

```
belongs_to :menu_item
belongs_to :venue
```

Menu Items

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :venue
has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
has_and_belongs_to_many :menu_attributes_menu_items_venues
```

I am then hoping to be able do something like this within my HAML template

```
- for item in @venue.menu_items
        .card
          %img{:src => "http://placehold.it/400x200?text=Coffee"}
            .card-divider
              = item.name
            .card-section
              %h4= item.menu_attributes.name.price
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
MenuAttribute.joins([{ menu_item: :menu_attributes_menu_items_venues }, :venue]).
    where('menu_items.id = menu_attributes_menu_items_venues.menu_item_id').
    where('menu_attributes.id = menu_attributes_menu_items_venues.menu_attribute_id').
    where('venues.id = menu_attributes_menu_items_venues.venue_id').
    select("menu_items.name", "menu_attributes.name", "menu_attributes_menu_items_venues.menu_attribute_value")
```

You actually don't even need those `where` caluses if the associations are setup properly and the table has correct foreign keys.

So, you should be able to just do something like this:

```
MenuAttribute.joins([{ menu_item: :menu_attributes_menu_items_venues }, :venue]).
    select("menu_items.name", "menu_attributes.name", "menu_attributes_menu_items_venues.menu_attribute_value")
```

Let me know if it works or not. I can update my answer after getting your feedback.

Comment: there isn't a way to achieve this via active record?

Comment: pure active record? I guess no.

Comment: I got this far - for item in @venue.menu_items
        .card
          %img{:src => "http://placehold.it/400x200?text=Coffee"}
            .card-divider
              = item.name
            .card-section
              %h4
                - for attr in item.menu_attributes